# Why do points where equipotential lines are most dense have the highest electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, vector-fields

[image]

Shown in the pictures are some points and equi-potential lines. 
At point A, the electric field is the strongest. My professor said it was becuase the lines are densest. So the change in voltage per length is the greatest.

But I think he forgot the minus sign before the derivative:

$$E=-\frac{dV}{dx}$$

According to this formula, the points at which the change in Voltage is zero, has a strong electric field than a point at which the change is huge. Clearly, $E=0>E=-1000$

Edit: Now I know some of you may argue that the direction of the field line is Arbitrary and so the minus sign has no significance. But...the direction is NOT arbitrary. Because the voltage goes from high to low from right to left, the positive point charge must be on the right on and the negative point charge must be on the left. So the field line is going from right to left as well.

Oh maybe, that is why! The x-axis is point from left to right. I don't know.

Comment: Observe that the electric field is, in general, a vector and thus only the magnitude of this vector can be a reasonable measure of the field's strength :)

Comment: yea but in this case, we only care about the x component

Comment: but still, the positive and negative $x$ directions are arbitrary, so the only meaningful concept of strength can be the magnitude again

Comment: Ok but a bit vague

Comment: This is like saying a person who weighs 200 pounds really weighs -200 pounds because the force vector points down.

Comment: Imagine you have two electric fields, one pointing left and the other pointing right. You put an proton in both fields, and one experiences a force right of 10 N (so positive) and the other experiences a force left of 1000 N (but negative as it is left). Which field would you say is stronger?

Comment: @knzhou that's a really nice idea. Think of all the diet products that could be advertised - "lose double your weight by changing your perspective" :)